# Is there a way to randomize the value to be selected after pulling a list of items from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, expo

This post might seems similar to [How do I get the proper text form from the firebase realtime database after querying via expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75387467/how-do-i-get-the-proper-text-form-from-the-firebase-realtime-database-after-quer) but it is not.

In this post, I would like to find out how do I randomize the shop names that I have retrieved from the database.

Currently the screen looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is 2 different shop names appearing after a search from my database by the cuisine. But I would like the code to help me to pick which shop name to display, is it possible? And how would I implement in my code?

My current code for the above image is this:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import {db} from '../firebase'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, onValue} from 'firebase/database'

const SubScreen2 = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey
  
  console.log(paramKey)
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  //const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  console.log(paramKey)
  useEffect (() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "food/" + paramKey);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) =>{
      const data = snapshot.val();
      const newPosts = Object.keys(data).map(key =>({
        id:key,
        ...data[key]
      })
      );
      console.log(newPosts);
      setToDoData(newPosts);
      
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      
      <Text style = {styles.header}></Text>
      {
        todoData.map((item,index) => {
          return(
            <View key ={index}>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.id}</Text>
                
                
            
            </View>          
            )
        })
      }
      </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen2
```

Comment: Are you asking [how to get a random node from the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+a+random+node+from+the+Firebase+Realtime+Database%3F)

Comment: Yes thats correct